# Jmeter: Error in Request Header when start test plan "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: jmeter

I have a HTTP Request sampler for a login form page. And added parameters like name and password and submit. But getting error below after start the test in Jmeter.

```
Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems Like You have selected post query option while sending the request that is why you are getting the above response.

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

You did not mentioned what type of verb[GET or POST] you are using for log in request . if it is get you don't have query options, if it is POST please make sure you did not selected Query option in order to avoid this issue.